# Locale English(Ireland,Euro) not available in Locale dropdown

Tags: locale

I have my Developer Org where "English(Ireland,Euro)" is avaialble in Locale dropdown in Language and Timezone. But, in my Customer Org that Locale is not avaibale in Locale dropdown. May I know the reason?

Comment: does both org have same settings related to multi currency, multi language .. or they have different settings ?

Comment: both have same settings. Multi Currency is not enable in both.